# Tool to enable carpooling

Tags: gratis

We are considering organizing carpooling at the place I work.

We are looking for a platform / website which allows every user to have an account, for people to register which days they want to carpool, and ideally also calculate the km's and costs saved.

Does anyone have experience with such a tool?

Note: that a paid platform is also an option, but a free tool is better of course :)